# Is angulus a diminutive?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, diminutive

The word *angulus* (angle or corner) looks like a diminutive.
Was it derived from some other word or stem using the diminutive *-ulus* suffix, or is looking like a diminutive coincidental?
It looks like it could be related to the verb *angere*, but I haven't found a related non-diminutive noun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

angulus is cognate with English “ankle” (and other Germanic words) and Russian “ugol” (corner) and its Slavic cognates, so the /l/ is Indo-European heritage, not a Latin innovation. PIE reconstructions such as *ang-(o)lo- or *h2eng-(o)lo- have been proposed.

angere “to strangle” is supposed to be from *h2emǵho-, with a palatal *ǵh.